# How to print a specific element of an array in a html table with angularjs?

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, html-table, dynamic-tables

I am learning Angular now and got stuck here. What I have tried is:

```
<tr ng-show="data in myData17.layouts | limitTo:2 | slice:1">
  <td>{{data.name}}</td>
  <td>{{data.cards[1].cardNo}}</td>
  <td>{{data.cards[1].cardType}}</td>
  <td>{{data.cards[1].ports[0].portNo}}</td>
  <td>{{data.cards[1].ports[0].portName}}</td>
  <td>{{data.cards[1].ports[0].portType}}</td>
  <td>{{data.cards[1].ports[0].portspeed}}</td>
  <td>{{data.cards[1].ports[0]["ds-scheduler-node-profile"]}}</td>                  
</tr>
```

where layouts is an array that has up to 10 elements in it but I want to access the data that is in index=1.

Comment: It is not so clear what you want to display. You need only one row? Can you show a sample of the data array? `ng-show` doesn't have that syntax, `ng-repeat` does

Comment: bill, in a simple way I wanted to display only one index value in an array of say 10 indexes. Thanks anyway I got help!

Comment: If this is the case, then you don't even need to use `ng-repeat`. There is no reason to loop through the entire array

Comment: I need ng-repeat to loop through that selected index which is again an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use ng-repeat instead of ng-show for looping and use $index for accessing item.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in myData17.layouts">
  <td ng-show="$index==0">{{data.name}}</td>
  <td ng-show="$index==0">{{data.cards[0].cardNo}}</td>
  <td ng-show="$index==0">{{data.cards[0].cardType}}</td>
  <td ng-show="$index==0">{{data.cards[0].ports[0].portNo}}</td>
  <td ng-show="$index==0">{{data.cards[0].ports[0].portName}}</td>
  <td ng-show="$index==0">{{data.cards[0].ports[0].portType}}</td>
  <td ng-show="$index==0">{{data.cards[0].ports[0].portspeed}}</td>
  <td ng-show="$index==0">{{data.cards[0].ports[0]["ds-scheduler-node-profile"]}}</td>                  
</tr>
```

Comment: Ashish this works fine. thanks but can I print those cardNo, cardType etc values dynamically using another ng-repeat inside but not sure how, any suggestions?

Comment: yes you can print those value also using nested ng-repeat 
<td ng-show="$index==0"><span ng-repeat="card in data.cards">{{card.cardNo}}</span></td>. For structure data you have to create table layout accordingly.